# How to select this HTML codes using Regular Expression?

Tags: html, regex

I have a few lines of HTML code :

```html
<div class="container header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">This is the target text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to select everything inside the `<div class="container header">` using Regular Expression ?

The end result should be :

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">This is the target text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: This is easily - and far more reliably - achieved using DOM nodes; *why* would you want to work with regular expressions to do this? What constraints are you working under? And - frankly - what solution did you come up with yourself that, presumably, failed? In what way?

Comment: I updated my answer and the live demo to take more cases into account.

Comment: @DavidThomas... I'm trying to scrape a page using PHP. Is it easier to use DOM nodes on PHP than regex? pls tell me more about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<div class="row">[ \n\s]*<div class="col-md-6">[^<]*<\/div>[ \n\s]*<\/div>
```

- `[\n\s]*` ensures you are only reading newspaces or spaces
- `[^<]*` reads everything excluding `<`, which is the character you stop at
- `<\/div>[ \n\s]*<\/div>` reads the two closing div tags you requested

Of course you must run it with the `s` option so that a dot matches newlines.

[Live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/1DJSAQ/3)

Answer (score 0):

[`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) can be used to parse html:

```js
var html = `
<div class="container header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">This is the target text</div>
  </div>
</div>`

var innerHTML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/xml').firstChild.innerHTML

console.log( innerHTML )
```